# asyncio Python for loop in text distance metric

Tags: python, for-loop, async-await, nlp, python-asyncio

I need to run a 40 metrics of distance (for similarity comparison between two strings) in a large list of strings using asyncio (I want to do not block the loop for while calculate), but the time processing for the async is almost the same as the normal processing, I do not know if I am missing something in the async code. The code I wrote is below:

```
import textdistance as td
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

s1 = a list of strings (+500000)
s2 = a list of strings (+500000)


async def metric_01(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.hamming.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_02(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.mlipns.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_03(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.levenshtein.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_04(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.damerau_levenshtein.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_05(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.jaro_winkler.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_06(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.strcmp95.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_07(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.needleman_wunsch.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_08(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.gotoh.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_09(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.smith_waterman.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_10(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.jaccard.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_11(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.sorensen_dice.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_12(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.tversky.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_13(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.overlap.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_14(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.tanimoto.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_15(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.cosine.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_16(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.monge_elkan.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_17(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.bag.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_18(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.lcsseq.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_19(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.lcsstr.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_20(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.ratcliff_obershelp.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_21(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.hamming.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_22(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.mlipns.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_23(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.levenshtein.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_24(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.damerau_levenshtein.normalized_distance(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_25(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.jaro_winkler.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_26(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.strcmp95.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_27(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.needleman_wunsch.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_28(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.gotoh.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_29(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.smith_waterman.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_30(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.jaccard.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_31(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.sorensen_dice.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_32(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.tversky.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_33(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.overlap.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_34(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.tanimoto.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_35(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.cosine.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_36(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.monge_elkan.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_37(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.bag.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_38(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.lcsseq.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_39(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.lcsstr.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)

async def metric_40(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    return td.ratcliff_obershelp.normalized_similarity(sentence_1, sentence_2)


functions = [metric_01, metric_02, metric_03, metric_04, metric_05, metric_06,
             metric_07, metric_08, metric_09, metric_10, metric_11, metric_12,
             metric_13, metric_14, metric_15, metric_16, metric_17, metric_18,
             metric_19, metric_20, metric_21, metric_22, metric_23, metric_24, 
             metric_25, metric_26, metric_27, metric_28, metric_29, metric_30,
             metric_31, metric_32, metric_33, metric_34, metric_35, metric_36,
             metric_37, metric_38, metric_39, metric_40]


async def calc(s1, s2):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        tasks = []
        for function in functions:
            task = asyncio.create_task(function(s1[i], s2[i]))
            tasks.append(task)
        res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        result.append(res)
    return result

result = asyncio.run(calc(s1, s2))
```

The code above has the same time of processing as if I run in synchronous mode. Can somenone help me to see where I am missing something.
Obs.: I know it is possible to use parallel, distributed or multi processing to do this task in a huge dataset, but I want to know if it is possible to use async and how.

Comment: you missed one big think - not all functions can be used with `async`. If `textdistance` doesn't have functions which use `await` then using `async` is useless. They will work the same way as without `async` - functions will have to wait for end of other functions. In this situation you have to use `threading` or `multiprocessing`

Comment: As I suspected but wasn't sure, thanks a lot. By the way, textdistance not acept async.